# How to get mysql to output rows for each key provided in where clause even if it is duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get duplicate output for duplicate keys in `where` clause. Is it possible to do that.

I have looked on

For example when I query

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE id IN (3,3,4)
```

I want the output:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 3  | tiger |
| 3  | tiger |
| 4  | lion  |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and output? For me it is giving 2 rows 
https://paiza.io/projects/OKPwR3GxdiqKjOZHDWH0Ig?language=mysql

Comment: `WHERE id IN (3)` should show all rows having id=3. Unless what you mean is to show it side by side? Which I see your expected output there seems like you want it side by side..

Comment: Yes, it does that. My problem is different. there's only one entry for three but I want to get its output twice when I provide it two times in the IN clause

Comment: That won't work for `IN` clause. `UNION` is the way but your `UNION` will increase according to how many duplicate you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

According to MYSQL documentation

> UNION followed with ALL keyword is used to combine the result from
>   multiple SELECT statements including duplicate rows into a single
>   result set.

According to above mentioned  description as a solution to problem,please try executing following SQL select query.

```
select name from table A where id in (3,3)
UNION ALL
select name from table A where id in (3,3)
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working for when i provide it two duplicate keys but doesn't when there's three. Will i need to put union all as many number of times as there are duplicate keys or there's a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a derived table and use `join`:

```
SELECT i.id, t.name
FROM (SELECT 3 as id UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 as id UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 as id 
     table t
     ON t.id = i.id;
```